# Get all values for group in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas groupby provides `first` and `last` to get the first and last values in a group. Is there a way to get all the values in a group as a list? I want to compute mean for some columns but get all values for other columns in a pandas groupby operation

```
        df_points = df_points.groupby(['field_id', 'Year']).agg({'Added_by': 'first',
                                                                 'Crop': 'first',
                                                                 'lat': 'first',
                                                                 'lon': 'first',
                                                                 'was': np.nanmean,
                                                                 'geometry': 'first'})
```

In this example, I want to get all values for the `was` column for each group (instead of the nanmean)

Comment: `'other_col': lambda x: x.values`

Comment: `'other_col': list`

Comment: @QuangHoang Don’t use `.values`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can just call `list`.

so in your `agg()` it would be `'was':list`.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['James', 'Mary', 'John', 'John'],
                    'B' : [30, 37, 30, 35],
                    'C' : [30, 37, 30, 35]})

df1.groupby('A').agg({'B':list, 'C':'sum'})

              B   C
A                  
James      [30]  30
John   [30, 35]  65
Mary       [37]  37
```

One thing to be careful of is that you can have one aggregation per column. The `agg` will take the *last* aggregation you supplied. So below, it will `sum` the `B` column, instead of making a second one.

```
df1.groupby('A').agg({'B':list, 'C':'sum', 'B':'sum'})

        B   C
A            
James  30  30
John   65  65
Mary   37  37
```